# Saliva that has a Anti Bacteria agent

Tags: bacteria

If a person does not brush their teeth or use mouth wash "Ever" yet there are no signs of bacteria build up or any signs of odor at the least,  **What does this tell us about the saliva that is produced in this person?**

Answer (score 4):

Nothing out of the ordinary, unless it is subjected to testing. Anything proposed outside of what is known about oral health and saliva is simply hypothesis.

Oral health could be influenced by diet (eating certain foods are less likely to feed oral bacteria), fluid consumption, salivary flow, or any number of things.

<sub>[A review of saliva: Normal composition, flow, and function](http://www.thejpd.org/article/S0022-3913%2801%2954032-9/abstract)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

That the saliva has anti-bacterial compunds in it? It also maintains a certain pH in the mouth.

Anyways the lack of bacterial build up and odor says more about the person's diet though.